# XPath not working in JQuery selector (JQuery version 1.7.1)

Tags: jquery, xpath, jquery-selectors, jquery-1.7

Below is a jQuery selector that works, and the value is set correctly into the text box.  Why doesn't the XPath code within the jQuery selector work?  I thought jQuery supported XPath.

**jQuery code working:**

```
$('html > body > form > div:nth-child(4) > label > input').val('hello world');
```

**jQuery code not working:**

```
$('/html/body/form/div[4]/label/input[1]').val('hello world');
```

**Documentation here:**

http://docs.jquery.com/DOM/Traversing/Selectors

... search for this code in the documentation above .... `$("/html/body//p")`

Comment: That link has a comment "This is an old version of the Selectors API" and the current version is at http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/ - you should check there.

Comment: +1 thanks for the info... it would be helpful if they'd put the words "DEPRECATED in version X" below code that doesn't work with the latest version

Comment: It would also help if they hadn't 4444ing broken it, but perhaps there's a way to plug XPath back in...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

jQuery does not support XPath syntax for selectors out of the box anymore.

If you look at that documentation you link to, you'll see it's for **version 1.1.2**, something from more than 5 years ago. It also says, in a **great big red box with centered text**:

> This is an old version of the Selectors API:
>
> #### [View the Current API](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors)

Comment: Can I get the object via XPath using regular JavaScript and then use that object in my jQuery code?  If so, how can I do that?

Comment: If the browser supports XPath in its JavaScript engine, then you should be able to. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Introduction_to_using_XPath_in_JavaScript although you should totally drop that and go all the way with jQuery.

Comment: For readers that are interested in the answer to my question in my last comment, use this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10094891/xpath-element-object-is-undefined-when-using-document-evaluate

Answer (score 3):

When the Xpath selectors were removed ([in JQuery 1.2](http://docs.jquery.com/Release%3ajQuery_1.2#XPath_Compatibility_Plugin)) the functionality was moved to a plugin, http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/xpath